# Need to collect the logs from application running inside AWS's EKS Pod

Tags: amazon-eks

I would like to achieve something similar as below but in AWS - EKS

In my kubeadm k8s cluster, if I have to collect application log from pod, I will run below command

`kubectl cp podName:/path/to/application/logs/logFile.log /location/on/master/`

But with AWS I am not sure, how to collect logs like above?

- One workaround is persist the logs on S3 with PV and PVC and then get them from there.

```
        volumeMounts:
          - name: logs-sharing
            mountPath: /opt/myapp/AppServer/logs/container
      volumes:
        - name: logs-sharing
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: logs-sharing-pvc
```

- Other way would be use sidecar container with a logging agent

But I would appreciate if there is any workaround which will as easy as the one I mentioned above that I follow with kubeadm

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Let say I using local machin(laptop) to connect to EKS cluster which has `AWS CLI` and `kubectl` installed. Now I want to get logs from one of pods , how would I do it with `kubectl cp podName:/path/to/logs/file/file.log`

Answer (score 0):

`...as easy as the one I mentioned above that I follow with kubeadm`

`kubectl cp` is a standard k8s command, you can use it for EKS, AKS, GKE etc.